# MySql query for records at every interval between two DateTime range

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

Following MySQL query provides records at times: `08:00:00, 09:00:00, 12:00:00, 15:00:00 etc` (divisible by 3, as specified in group by), but I want records for times `08:00:00, 11:00:00, 14:00:00, 17:00:00 etc.` i.e. interval from my given start time. How can I achieve this?

```
SELECT *  
FROM  `data_10082016`  
WHERE CREATED_AT BETWEEN  "2016-08-11 08:00:00" AND  "2016-08-15 08:00:00" 
GROUP BY DATE( DATETIME ) , FLOOR( HOUR( DATETIME ) /3 )  
ORDER BY  `data_10082016`.`id` ASC
```

Comment: The query in this question isn't guaranteed to return any particular rows within the group; the values returned will be from some (indeterminate) row in the group. Note that the query in this question relies on a MySQL extension to GROUP BY. Other RDBMS would throw an error about "non aggregate in SELECT list not in GROUP BY". (We can get MySQL to behave in a more standard way by including ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY in the sql_mode variable.) To get values from particular rows, that would require additional predicates in the WHERE clause, or some clever expressions in the SELECT list.

Comment: Thanls @spencer7593, I am actually learning MySQL now... Aggregates like?? Actually, I need rows closest to hour like 12:00:25, 12:01:23, 11:59:42...

Comment: Aggregate functions like SUM(), MAX(), MIN(), AVG() operate on a group of rows to return a single value. With the GROUP BY operation, there is potential for several rows to be collapsed into a single row. The MySQL extension to GROUP BY will allow a non-aggregate expression (for example, a plain column) to be used in the SELECT list. And MySQL will return a value from some row in the group. There is no guarantee the value will be the lowest or highest, or come from the earliest, closest, latest row. That's what is meant when we say the value is "indeterminate"

Comment: I am just pointing out that if there are rows with the same date and time values of 12:00, 12:15, 13:30, 14:44... the GROUP BY is going to collapse all of those rows into a single row. And the values returned for the columns in the SELECT list aren't guaranteed to be from any one particular row... the value can be from any of those four rows.

Comment: Ohh.. Thanks @spencer7593... Can you suggest me doc, where I can learn aggregation on groups so that i can make use of them??

Comment: Really, Thanks @spencer7593, I didnt know this earlier, I will now first study this and build the query accordingly... Can you recommend any good doc on it??

Comment: I recommend the MySQL Reference Manual.  If you are running MySQL 5.7 http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html  , http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html

Comment: Okay... I will study it... thanks...

Comment: @spencer7593, As you explained before if for any particular time there are more than one row i.e. like if for time 12:00, there are more than one rows then group by collapses these all rows and returns only single row... So, is there any possibility to get all the rows which have time 12:00 and also at every 3 hours, For eg., if there are four rows every hour then I need to fetch all those four rows at every 3rd hour from given time like results would be.`4 rows from time closest to 08:00:00, then 4 rows from time closest to 11:00:00, then 4 rows from time closest to 14:00:00, and goes on... `

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want the records corresponding to these times rather than an aggregate measure across the intervals between these times....

```
SELECT *  
FROM  `data_10082016`  
WHERE CREATED_AT BETWEEN  "2016-08-11 08:00:00" AND  "2016-08-15 08:00:00" 
AND MOD(HOUR( DATETIME )+8, 3) = 0
ORDER BY  `data_10082016`.`id` ASC
```

Will give you records at 3 hour intervals from 8am.

Getting the records *closest* to the hour is a whole lot more difficult and will need a reference table. Not something to be attempted with a great deal of expertise in SQL and a lit of time.

Comment: Thanks @symcbean, I think it should be like `MOD(HOUR( DATETIME )-8, 3) = 0`... With your query, the hours I am getting are: `10,13,16,19...`

Also, however, with only `WHERE condition` it doesnt give me records closest to hour i.e. like 12:00:25, 12:01:23, 11:59:42 are closest to 12:00:00... Instead what I am getting is all records with given hours (like if `08` is the hour then all records with hour `08` are obtained like `08:01:33`, `08:02:33`, etc.) as we are evaluating only hours in `WHERE` part...

Comment: Yes, you're right on both counts - even getting the records on the hour is not trivial. Adding `AND 0=MINUTE(datetime)` should the time exactly on the hour - but that's not what you want.

Comment: Yes exactly, that is not exactly I want... I want the closest one possible... Also, With grouping, if certain rows have same time, then those all are collapsed into one as explained by @spencer7593 in the comments of question, what I want is, all rows (even with same time) and closest to hour... Also, I tried adding `MINUTE=0` condition, but the thing is, it is less probable that I will find records exactly at `00` minute and thus results with `MINUTE=0` are almost half of what I want...

Answer (score 0):

You just add an offset (+2, -7, ...) to your `floor(...)` function, e.g.

```
...
group by date(created_at), floor(hour(created_at) / 3) + 2
...
```

Comment: Thanks, @Olaf, Its giving `08:00:00, 10:00:00, 13:00:00, etc.` Tried with offset '1' and got the results, but not exactly i.e. with offset '1', these are the hours that i get: `08, 11, 14, 17, 20, 23, '00', 02, 05`... i.e. this `00` is unwanted here..

Comment: Why am i getting `00` here ?

Comment: Maybe try `floor(hour(created_at) / 3) + 2`. Although, from the comments,  maybe I misunderstood what you want to achieve.

Comment: Grouping with `floor(hour(created_at) - 8 / 3)` worked well along with [@symcbean](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39357747/6168395) 's `WHERE` condition (to avoid unwanted `00` hours)

Comment: But, when trying to filter selection with field `type` using `WHERE` and this query, I am not able to get all records from all `types` that I have filtered... Following is my new query:
`SELECT *  FROM  data_10082016 WHERE type IN ('prod','energy','other') AND MOD((HOUR( DATETIME ) - 8 ) , 3
) =0 AND CREATED_AT BETWEEN  "2016-08-11 08:00:00" AND  "2016-08-15 08:00:00" GROUP BY DATE( DATETIME ) , FLOOR( HOUR( DATETIME )  - 8 /3 ) ORDER BY  data_10082016.id ASC`...

Comment: With this above query, I get records of only those with `type='prod'` and it is due to auto grouping by MySql as it is without any aggregates as explained by @spencer7593 in comments of the question... So, what can I do to get records for all `types` given in `WHERE` part...??

Comment: Looking at the comments, you don't want or need `group by`, but simply some ordering (`order by`). It's just not clear what kind of ordering, maybe `order by created_at` is already enough.

Comment: If you want a solution to your problem, you should provide both a sample of your data, *and* a desired result. Everything else will be just guessing from my side.